# NUXT.js 3 setCookie gives error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHeader')"

Tags: jwt, nuxt.js

When a user logs in successfully this `sendRefreshToken` method is executed to send the refresh token.

```
export const sendRefreshToken = (event, token) => {
    setCookie(event.res, "refresh_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true
    })
}
```

But this gives a server error 500 back, this is the error i see in the console:

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHeader')
  at appendResponseHeader (/C:/Development/Node_Projects/quiz/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:289:27)
  at setCookie (/C:/Development/Node_Projects/quiz/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:358:3)
  at sendRefreshToken (/C:/Development/Node_Projects/quiz/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:649:3)
  at /C:/Development/Node_Projects/quiz/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:697:3
  at async Server.toNodeHandle (/C:/Development/Node_Projects/quiz/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:698:7)
  at async Server.toNodeHandle (/C:/Development/Node_Projects/quiz/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:698:7)
```

Comment: You're using Nuxt3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing just `event` to `setCookie` instead of `event.res`.

```
export const sendRefreshToken = (event, token) => {
    setCookie(event, "refresh_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true
    })
}
```

I looked in the [source code](https://github.com/unjs/h3/blob/10eab1b237b0e01eb9337da653faafb9b9616905/src/utils/cookie.ts#L47) quickly and it seems h3 is trying to access `event.res`.

Comment: This indeed solved it, thx felix :)